# Error while manipulating values from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Bobi from Macedonia, and I stumbled upon one ugly problem with
my JavaScript/jQuery code.

I want to enter some values in my textarea, and then according to the specific formula
those values need to be calculated and the result need to be presented with alert.

Here is my code...

```
//First this is my formula
function calc(data) { 
  ret = []; 

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
ret[i] = (3.5 + data[i] + 0.5 * (data[i] - 3));
 } 
   return ret; 
 }

//Now, taking values from the text area using valHooks
$.valHooks.textarea = {
get: function(elem) {
return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
  }
};

$('button').click(function() {

//in this step the values are successfully taken from the textarea 
    var  sample = {};
sample.data = $('textarea').val();
    //alert(sample.data);  <-- this works fine


var result = {};
    result.data = calc(sample.data);   //but here seems to be the problem
    alert(result.data);                //the alert shows some gibberish values
```

So for example, if I enter these values 1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0, 2.5, 2.8...
The alert need to show these calculated values: 4.4, 7.85, 6.95, 8.0, 5.75, 6.2...

Here is also jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Avramoski/skqG4/

I know that I am missing something small, but God knows what it is...
Please help! :(

Comment: Well, in your Fiddle, you are missing jQuery (you need to include it). and you are missing `})` for your `$(function(){ ...`. And `data.length` in your `calc` function is the length of the string you pass in. Are you expecting an array there?

Comment: Where are you splitting the input string into an array of numbers?

Comment: Try to add `type="button"` attribute on your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the following three changes as i noted.. and enjoy codding.. :)

```
 function calc(data) { 
     ret = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     data[i] = parseFloat(data[i]); // here u want to parse ur string to float
    ret[i] = (3.5 + data[i] + 0.5 * (data[i] - 3));
    ret[i] = Math.round(ret[i] * 100) / 100; // this code for get rounded answer like exactly u needed 
     } 
       return ret; 
     }

$.valHooks.textarea = {
get: function(elem) {
return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
  }
};

$('button').click(function() {

    var  sample = {};
sample.data = $('textarea').val();
sample.data = sample.data.split(","); //textarea value transferring to array
    //alert(sample.data);


var result = {};
    result.data = calc(sample.data);   
    alert(result.data);   
} // and dont miss this curly bracket :D
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/skqG4/5/) link to demo result.

You must check parseFloat number was valid.

```
        $(function () {


function calc(data) { 
      ret = []; 
    var res=data.split(',');
 for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
     var parseNumber=parseFloat(res[i]);
    ret[i] =  (3.5 + parseNumber + 0.5 * (parseNumber - 3)).toFixed(2);
  } 
  return ret; 
}

//Taking values from the text area using valHooks
$.valHooks.textarea = {
    get: function(elem) {
    return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
}
};

$('button').click(function() {

    var result = {};
        result.data = calc(sample.data);   
        alert(result.data); 

});
});
```